# Edit elements of the list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list called ids:

```
ids = ['id = 1234', 'id=223345', 'id=456', 'id=4562347', 'id=521345678']
```

How to create new list in python that contains only numbers like:

```
new_ids=['1234', '223345', '456', '4562347', '521345678']
```

Comment: `ids_new = [i.split("=")[-1].strip() for i in ids]` ? Basic list comprehension...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` and `replace()` functions to get the list without any text:

```
ids = ['id = 1234', 'id=223345', 'id=456', 'id=4562347', 'id=521345678']
print([i.split("=")[1].replace(" ", "") for i in ids])
```

**Output:**

```
['1234', '223345', '456', '4562347', '521345678']
```

Also, you can achieve the same result by using regular expressions as follows:

```
import re

ids = ['id = 1234', 'id=223345', 'id=456', 'id=4562347', 'id=521345678']
print([re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i) for i in ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by `list comprehension` using `strip` to remove the spaces:

```
new_ids = [x[-1].strip() for x in ids]
```

if you want to convert them to `int` type you can do it right away in the list comprehension:

```
new_ids = [int(x[-1].strip()) for x in ids]
```

you could do it also by `map` but i don't raccomend it because it is slower and the list comprehension is more readable

```
new_ids = list(map(lambda x:int(x[-1].strip()),ids))
```

and also there is the `regex` way wich is the slowest but if you prefer it you can use it

```
import re as regex
new_ids = [regex.search(r'(\d+)',x).string for x in ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re 
new_ids = [re.findall(r'\d+', id) for id in ids]
```